# How does this color function work?

Tags: javascript, colors, bit-manipulation

I've come across this little function that returns some color value. I cannot understand the bit manipulations it's doing.

```
//Given a color, returns the ARGB values of that color in an array
var getColor = function(color){
    return [color >> 24&255, color >> 16&255,
    color >> 8&255, color&255];
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's taking a 32-bit value and chopping it up into 8-bit pieces. The `>>` operator is the **right shift** operator, so the first thing that goes into the array is the upper 8 bits (32-8 is 24).

Each shifted value is ANDed with 255 (hex `0xff`) to isolate just the lower 8 bits (post-shift).

So if you start off with `4AE109B0`, the function will:

- shift right by 24, isolating the `4A`
- shift right by 16, isolating the `E1`
- shift right by 8, isolating the `09`
- and finally just isolate the original low 8 bits to get `B0`

The result would be the array

```
[0x4A, 0xE1, 0x09, 0xB0]
```

Personally I would parenthesize the shift and mask operations, because I can never remember the operator precedence:

```
function getColor(color){
    return [
      (color >> 24) & 255,
      (color >> 16) & 255,
      (color >> 8) & 255,
      color & 255
    ];
};
```

Comment: Well explained. If I understand correctly, the idea of this function is for you to pass in a 32-bit color value and get the separated ARGB color channel in a nice array?

Comment: @Revoo precisely! Of course the function doesn't know if it's ARGB or RGBA or GRAB or anything; it just delivers the bytes.